# Spring Boot 1.3.1.RELEASE + IntelliJ Debug mode

Tags: spring-boot

I have built some Spring Data Rest app with Spring Boot with just in memory security, all with Gradle:

```
dependencies {
runtime("mysql:mysql-connector-java")

compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")

compile("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.14.8")

compile("com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:3.7.0")
compile("com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-apt:3.7.0")

compile("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1")

testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

All works fine except IntelliJ Debug mode - when I try to debug my Main class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);}
}
```

I get the below exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionOutcome.inverse(Lorg/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionOutcome;)Lorg/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionOutcome;
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$NotJwtTokenCondition.getMatchOutcome(ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration.java:369)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:45)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:92)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:190)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:304)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:235)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:218)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:435)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:258)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:218)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:435)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:258)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:218)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:435)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:389)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:305)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:611)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
at com.xxx.core.Application.main(Application.java:26)

2016-01-15 21:40:34.007  INFO 14606 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5ddf0d24: startup date [Fri Jan 15 21:40:32 GMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-01-15 21:40:34.011  WARN 14606 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5ddf0d24: startup date [Fri Jan 15 21:40:32 GMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:346)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:882)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:843)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
at com.xxx.core.Application.main(Application.java:26)

2016-01-15 21:40:34.012  WARN 14606 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5ddf0d24: startup date [Fri Jan 15 21:40:32 GMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:890)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:843)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
at com.xxx.core.Application.main(Application.java:26)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionOutcome.inverse(Lorg/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionOutcome;)Lorg/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionOutcome;
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$NotJwtTokenCondition.getMatchOutcome(ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration.java:369)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:45)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:92)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:190)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:304)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:235)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:218)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:435)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:258)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:218)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:435)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:258)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:218)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:435)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:389)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:305)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:611)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
at com.xxx.core.Application.main(Application.java:26)
```

If I switch from springBootVersion = '1.3.1.RELEASE' into 1.1.8 for example (and remove devtools as it comes with 1.3.1), exception is not being thrown and debug works fine.

I tried to remove security starter but it didn't help.
Maybe you have encountered similar behavior? What do I miss here?

Comment: `ConditionOutcome.inverse`, the method reported as missing, is new in 1.3.0. It looks like IDEA is messing up the classpath and giving you an older version somehow. Running with `-verbose:class` will let you see where the class is being loaded from.

Comment: `Loaded org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionOutcome from file:/Users/xxxx/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.1.8.RELEASE/d270f6883ce8a9b092fbbd31473a8d1c4d5e3ffd/spring-boot-autoconfigure-**1.1.8.RELEASE.jar**]`. Removing this package from Gradle cache did the job in terms of the above error but there were others, similar ones related to spring-core and embedded tomcat. Again, removing Gradle cache did the job. Why and how IntelliJ messes that? I do not know... Thanks for the hint!